# In PostgreSQL equality operator working, but ILIKE not

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 11 database, that running under Docker container, created from image `postgres-11`.

After I have replaced image to `postgis/postgis:11-2.5-alpine`, I faced some following strange behaviour.

```sql
foodmarkets=# select id, nickname from public.user where nickname = 'test';
 id | nickname 
----+----------
(0 rows)

foodmarkets=# select id, nickname from public.user where nickname ilike 'test';
 id  | nickname 
-----+----------
 128 | Test
 177 | test
(2 rows)
```

I copying `test` from second query results, pasting to first query and getting `0 rows` again.

In development mode equality comparison is working.

I doubt, that I'm typing something incorrect, because in production mode authorisation feature has stopped working, because it relies on the same query.

Whats wrong here?

Can different docker image be a reason?

Comment: Looks like equality is case-sensitive which I'm sure you are aware of... My only other guess is that there could be a DB-level setting that would flip the behavior and that in upgrading you might have lost that behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrossard, it is but it still should find `'test'`.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the second row with 'test' - yeah sorry about that @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Could be index corruption. Can you post `EXPLAIN` output for both queries? Does it change if you set `enable_indexscan` and `enable_bitmapscan` to `off`?

Comment: Do you have an index on `nickname`? What happens if you run `reindex public.user`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `user` is a bad name for a table, because it's a keyword and a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

It was index problem.

```sql
REINDEX INDEX user_nickname_key;
```